Max-flow-min-cut: equivalence between two graphs?
The problem of finding max-flow–min-cut between two vertices in a graph is well-established in algorithms and graph theory. However, I am interested in a related but distinct problem:
There are two directed acyclic graphs, $ G_1 $ over vertices $S\cup C_1 \cup T$ and $ G_2 $ over vertices $S\cup C_2 \cup T$, each with the same source vertices $ S $ and sink vertices $ T $, while the internal structures and corresponding vertices $C_1$ and $C_2$ differ.
The question is, how to efficiently determine (e.g., by graphical criteria on $ G_1 $ and $ G_2 $) whether, for every source $ s_i \in S $ and sink $ t_j \in T $, the max-flow–min-cut value from $ s_i $ to $ t_j $ is identical in both $ G_1 $ and $ G_2 $?
This question might be useful since one may usually only care about the value/size of max-flow-min-cut from places to places, instead of the specific inner structures. Such equivalence check would then help to e.g., simplify structures.
So I'm wondering if there are known results or insights on such flow-equivalence between graphs. Any guidance or pointers to related literature would be appreciated.

Remark: In my particular setting, all edges are unweighted and all paths from $ s_i $ to $ t_j $ must be vertex-disjoint in $C$ part, that is, I am looking for the minimum number of vertices in $C$ required to block all directed paths from $ s_i $ to $ t_j $. However, I believe the question above is of broader interest beyond this particular setting.

Why do you expect this to be possible?
